# How to make a page both “private” and “password protected”

Tags: plugins, posts, password

I’m working on a website which requires these two type of access for each post. (I mean, each post can be viewable in both of these cases)

1- Registered users in specific groups should be able to view the post.

2- Non-registered users should be able to view the post using a password.

I tested different plugins and settings to implement these scenarios but with no success. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Im really inexperienced with wordpress but i googled a few sec on google and maybe this will help.

function is_user_logged_in() {

$user = wp_get_current_user();

//Try to detect if the user is in a group here

return $user->exists();

}

Maybe you can try to do something with the page if the user is detected as user and in what group it is.

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/